# After new program installation: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005):

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, autodesk-inventor

My program is being used in our company on 20+ PC's and is running without any problems. But now one PC has installed Inventor 2020 which updated some generaly used DLL's (I don't know which ones) since that installation I get the following Error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External
> component has thrown an exception.

The error occurred when the app opens a DBConnection to Microsoft acces. One example of the connection below.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();


OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

string sql = "select * from PendingOrders";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
conn.Open();


OleDbDataReader reader;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

From my understanding there is one DLL that throws an exception, how can I figure out which one? Or even better find a workaround to make it work again.

thank you in advance!

Update:
After using DebugView (DbgView.exe) to debug on the users PC I can see the following.

```
ModLoad: 7c450000 7c7a6000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
ModLoad: 74f00000 74ffb000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 76a30000 76a3e000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSASN1.dll
ModLoad: 08e40000 08ea8000   image08e40000
ModLoad: 0c670000 0c6d8000   image0c670000
ModLoad: 00000000`7c7b0000 00000000`7c7fc000   System.Transactions.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`0fde0000 00000000`0fe2c000   System.Transactions.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`7c7b0000 00000000`7c7fc000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`7c800000 00000000`7c8cb000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`7c8d0000 00000000`7c8f2000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSDART.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`71920000 00000000`71928000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`7c900000 00000000`7ca54000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comsvcs.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`7ca60000 00000000`7cabd000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`7cac0000 00000000`7cb63000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9619_none_508d9c7abcbd32b6\MSVCR90.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`78d30000 00000000`79ef7000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\mso.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`72ba0000 00000000`72f01000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msi.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6a2e0000 00000000`6a306000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\srpapi.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`79f00000 00000000`7a108000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACECORE.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`7a110000 00000000`7a19e000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9619_none_508d9c7abcbd32b6\MSVCP90.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`10660000 00000000`10a7a000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\Cultures\office.odf
ModLoad: 00000000`10660000 00000000`10a7a000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\Cultures\office.odf
ModLoad: 00000000`10a80000 00000000`10b55000   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\1033\ACEWSTR.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`1c440000 00000000`2096b000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\MSORES.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`1c440000 00000000`2096b000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\MSORES.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`67aa0000 00000000`67ab9000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DavClnt.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`53fd0000 00000000`53fda000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DAVHLPR.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`10a80000 00000000`10ce3000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\1033\MSOINTL.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`10a80000 00000000`10ce3000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\1033\MSOINTL.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`6ccf0000 00000000`6cecd000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`24b70000 00000000`24c45000   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\1033\ACEWSTR.DLL
(136c.2a98): Unknown exception - code c06d007e (first chance)
(136c.2a98): Unknown exception - code c06d007e (first chance)
(136c.2a98): Unknown exception - code c06d007e (first chance)
ModLoad: 00000000`24b70000 00000000`24d00000   image00000000`24b70000
ModLoad: 00000000`24d00000 00000000`24e90000   image00000000`24d00000
ModLoad: 00000000`7a1a0000 00000000`7a2a5000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DebugView (DbgView.exe), which is good for identifying this kind of exceptions,  from SysInternals.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I used the debugger and shared the results. If I understand this correctly the problem is in the ACEWSTR.DLL however when I look at this it has not been changed since 2012.

Comment: you can't relay on modified date. compare the versions of the dll with  the working one